# Changing text color at the end of Truncate Razor helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I have a basic Truncate Razor helper and I am trying to change the color of the appended content in `<text></text>`. This element is parsed by the razor engine so I can't use encoded html/css (at least I haven't found a way) Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the the basic Truncate Helper:

```
@helper Truncate(string input, int length)
{
    if (input.Length <= length)
    {
        @input
    }
    else
    {
        @input.Substring(0, length)<text> ...more</text> <!-- here //-->
    }
}

// Implementation of Truncate helper
    <textarea readonly>@Truncate(comment.Content, 250)</textarea>
```

Note: It acts like a link with [Craig's jQuery textAreaExpander](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-auto-expanding-textarea-3/) which expands `textarea` on click

Comment: You can call the parent div and then say `#parentDiv textarea { Color: Red; }`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I only want the ... more to have new css. After thinking about it I may just use dot dot dot jQuery as it would probably make more sense to do it on client side anyways.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use `<span></span>` tags around the text. To do so, your `Truncate` helper would look like this:

```
public static HtmlString Truncate(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string input, int length)
{
    if (input.Length <= length)
    {
        return new HtmlString(input);
    }

    input = input.Substring(0, length);

    // Build the span tags
    TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
    span.SetInnerText(" ... more");

    // Change the text color by either adding the style attribute or a class
    span.MergeAttribute("style", "color: red;");
    span.AddCssClass("some-class");

    return new HtmlString(input + span.ToString());
}
```

Then call the helper using `@Html.Truncate(comment.Content, 250)`.

Comment: Nice. I was heading in that direction. Wouldn't the signature be public static HtmlString Truncate(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string input, int length)? I also heard to use MvcHtmlString over HtmlString but idk?

Comment: It is not Html Encoding the span for some reason. Close though.

Comment: Hm, I just tested it and it seems to be working fine. You may want to try using `span.InnerHtml = " ... more"` instead of `span.SetInnerText(" ... more")`. If that doesn't work, you can always wrap the call to the `Truncate` helper with `@Html.Raw()`, though that somewhat defeats the purpose of creating the helper in the first place.

Comment: I am an idiot. That's what you get for working too many hours straight. This content is going in a textarea and of course you cannot nest elements in textarea.